# facebook button showing only once when outputting it via while loop

Tags: facebook, while-loop, share

I'm using Gallerific with history plugin. In the while loop where I print all the images I want to add a facebook share button for each image using the specific image-url given by the history-plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"></script>
$images=mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM images etc.");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($images)) {

<li><a class='thumb' name='imagename' href='url-to-image' title='description' onclick='clickedThumbnail()'><img src='url-to-thumb' alt='".$row['comment']."'/></a>
<div class='caption'>
<a name=\"fb_share\" type=\"button_count\" share_url=\"http://url-to-image-made-by-the-history-plugin\">Share</a>
</div>
}
```

My problem is that it is only printing the facebook share button once. In the first while-loop. On the rest of the images it is printing the content of the `<a>`-tag ('Share') with the right attributes, but it is not clickable. I've tried without 'share' in the `<a>`-element but then I get nothing on the other images. But I always get the correct FB-button on the first image.
According to [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) I only have to include the javascript once even though I'm using several Facebook buttons on one page.
I have also tried to put several facebook-buttons outside the while-loop and it works fine.
Also, when I type the direct url to the images given by the history plugin it works fine. So my conclusion is that is has to do with printing the facebook-buttons from a while-loop..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this approach instead http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/
by changing some variables dynamically for each image. Works like a charm!

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is deprecated. See:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

You will want to use the share functionality that is part of the like button.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Sample URL to the broken code so we can look at the output from your while loop?